# How does Ionic 2 work with Angular 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm beginning to learn Angular 2 and Ionic 2. How do I2 and A2 work together?

Is A2 build inside of I2 like it has to implement new updates of A2 before you can use the newest A2 features?

Or is I2 just an extention of A2?

Hope the question is clear..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic 2 builds upon angular 2. It takes Angular 2 and adds additional features, like different routing, styles, etc.

The current Ionic beta implements angular 2 rc4.

That means, you're right. Ionic 2 will be behind angular 2 in terms of updates.

Comment: Thanks thats all i wanted to know!